# Como transformar várias colunas em 2 colunas com vba?

Tags: excel-vba, columns

Eu tenho uma planilha com as seguintes informações.

[image: planilha atual]

Quero criar uma nova sheet com algumas colunas dessa planilha e transformar as colunas Nominal, Umidade, Primeira_Entrega,
Grau Bebida, Standard, Medicinal e Restr_Horario em uma coluna chamada ITEM e o valor dessas colunas em outra coluna chamada FLAG.

A minha nova planilha ficaria assim:

[image: Nova tabela]

Além disso quero criar a coluna N_ITEM que é baseada no valor da coluna ITEM.

Se Item = STANDARD então N_ITEM = 1,

Se Item = NOMINAL, UMIDADE, GRAU_BEBIDA, MEDICINAL então N_ITEM = 2

Se Item = PRIMEIRA_ENTREGA então N_ITEM = 4

Se Item = RESTR_HORARIO então N_ITEM = 5.

Eu fiz a macro abaixo, mas não está funcionando...

```
Public Sub Atualizar()
'
'faz outra tabela listando cada ganho individual
'facilita a manipulação de pivot's
Dim BD As Worksheet
Dim base As Worksheet
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim itens As Range
Dim k As Long

Set BD = Sheets("Base_Distribuicao")
Set base = Sheets("base")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With base
.Range("A:M").ClearContents
.Range("a1").Value = "Cod_JDE"
   .Range("B1").Value = "CNPJ_8"
    .Range("C1").Value = "CNPJ"
    .Range("D1").Value = "CLIENTE"
    .Range("E1").Value = "REGIAO"
    .Range("F1").Value = "SUBREGIAO"
    .Range("G1").Value = "NEGOCIO"
    .Range("H1").Value = "PUBLICO_PRIVADO"
    .Range("I1").Value = "CDL_RESPONSAVEL"
    .Range("J1").Value = "PRODUTO"
    .Range("K1").Value = "ITEM"
    .Range("L1").Value = "N_ITEM"
    .Range("M1").Value = "FLAG"
End With
BD.Select
k = BD.Range("A1", BD.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
For c = 1 To 7 'contagem de colunas dos itens, ajuda a generalizar o preenchimento por offset
If itens Is Nothing Then 'definindo a ptimeira coluna
Set itens = BD.Range("A1:AB5000").Find(what:="Nominal")
itens.Offset(1, 0).Select
Else
Set itens = itens.Offset(0, 1) 'definindo as colunas restantes
itens.Offset(1, 0).Select 'primeiro flag do item
End If
For b = 1 To k
If ActiveCell.Value <> "" And ActiveCell.Value <> "-" Then
base.Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert
Else
base.Range("A2") = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -(5 + c)).Value
base.Range("B2") = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14 - c).Value
base.Range("C2") = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 15 - c).Value
base.Range("D2") = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 16 - c).Value
base.Range("E2") = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17 - c).Value
base.Range("F2") = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 18 - c).Value
base.Range("G2") = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 19 - c).Value
base.Range("H2") = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 20 - c).Value
base.Range("I2") = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -(3 + c)).Value
base.Range("J2") = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -(2 + c)).Value
base.Range("M2") = ActiveCell.Value
base.Range("K2") = itens.Value

End If
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select ' proximo flag
Next
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Olá Thaís, bem-vinda! Por favor, se puder, deixe o enunciado mais claro e as vezes mais simplificado porque ficaria mais fácil de responder. 
Ao invés de colocar o problema real, contextual da sua empresa, poderia diminuir e fazer a pergunta direto ao ponto:
Tenho uma planilha A com colunas (nome, rua, bairro, cidade, numero, cep) - gostaria de criar uma coluna B, com as colunas nome e endereço - é o mesmo problema mas de forma que as pessoas entendam melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Thaís,

Tudo bem com você?

Minha sugestão de código ficou gigante, mas acredito que resolverá seu problema.

Primeiramente, note que a estrutura das abas que eu usei para testar são as seguintes:

- Aba "Base_Distribuicao":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aba "base":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Basicamente, o que eu fiz foi copiar os cabeçalhos e valores que você queria transformar em colunas como células transpostas na aba base.

E, para preencher as demais linhas com os valores correspondentes, eu fiz o código percorrer célula por célula da aba "Base_Distribuição" e ir colando na aba "base.

Sugiro fortemente que você dê uma lida no meu código e teste "debugando (ou seja, pressionando a tecla F8 linha a linha)", pois para o código funcionar bem os comandos precisam corresponder exatamente à estrutura da planilha.

Por fim, segue aqui:

```
Sub Transposicao()

Dim W       As Worksheet
Dim WB      As Worksheet
Dim A       As Integer
Dim B       As Integer
Dim C       As Integer
Dim L       As Integer
Dim UltCel  As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set W = Sheets("Base_Distribuicao")
Set WB = Sheets("base")

WB.Select
WB.Range("A2:M1048576").Clear

W.Select
A = 2
B = 2
C = 2
'Set Col = W.Range("I1:O1")
Set UltCel = W.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)

Do While A <= UltCel.Row

    'Copia as células da aba Base_Distribuicao a serem transpostas e cola na aba base, transpondo
    W.Select
    W.Range("I1:O1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    WB.Select
    WB.Range("J" & C).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    
    'Copia os valores correspondentes para a coluna FLAG
    W.Select
    W.Range("I" & A).Select
    Selection.Copy
    WB.Select
    WB.Range("K" & C).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    W.Select
    W.Range("J" & A).Select
    Selection.Copy
    WB.Select
    WB.Range("K" & C + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    W.Select
    W.Range("K" & A).Select
    Selection.Copy
    WB.Select
    WB.Range("K" & C + 2).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    W.Select
    W.Range("L" & C).Select
    Selection.Copy
    WB.Select
    WB.Range("K" & C + 3).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    W.Select
    W.Range("M" & A).Select
    Selection.Copy
    WB.Select
    WB.Range("K" & C + 4).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    W.Select
    W.Range("N" & A).Select
    Selection.Copy
    WB.Select
    WB.Range("K" & C + 5).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    W.Select
    W.Range("O" & A).Select
    Selection.Copy
    WB.Select
    WB.Range("K" & C + 6).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    'Copia os demais valores referentes ao respectivo IDE
    
    ''Copia o IDE
    B = WB.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For L = 1 To 7
        W.Select
        W.Range("C" & A).Select
        Selection.Copy
        WB.Select
        WB.Range("A" & B).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        B = B + 1
    Next L
    
    ''Copia o CNPJ
    B = WB.Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For L = 1 To 7
        W.Select
        W.Range("V" & A).Select
        Selection.Copy
        WB.Select
        WB.Range("B" & B).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        B = B + 1
    Next L
    
    ''Copia o nome do cliente
    B = WB.Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For L = 1 To 7
        W.Select
        W.Range("W" & A).Select
        Selection.Copy
        WB.Select
        WB.Range("C" & B).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        B = B + 1
    Next L
    
    'Copia a região atual
    B = WB.Range("D1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For L = 1 To 7
        W.Select
        W.Range("X" & A).Select
        Selection.Copy
        WB.Select
        WB.Range("D" & B).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        B = B + 1
    Next L
    
    'Copia o subgrupo
    B = WB.Range("E1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For L = 1 To 7
        W.Select
        W.Range("Y" & A).Select
        Selection.Copy
        WB.Select
        WB.Range("E" & B).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        B = B + 1
    Next L
    
    'Copia o negócio
    B = WB.Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For L = 1 To 7
        W.Select
        W.Range("Z" & A).Select
        Selection.Copy
        WB.Select
        WB.Range("F" & B).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        B = B + 1
    Next L
    
    'Copia o públlico/privado
    B = WB.Range("G1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For L = 1 To 7
        W.Select
        W.Range("AA" & A).Select
        Selection.Copy
        WB.Select
        WB.Range("G" & B).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        B = B + 1
    Next L
    
    'Copia o CDL_Responsável
    B = WB.Range("H1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For L = 1 To 7
        W.Select
        W.Range("E" & A).Select
        Selection.Copy
        WB.Select
        WB.Range("H" & B).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        B = B + 1
    Next L
    
    'Copia o Installation Product
    B = WB.Range("I1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For L = 1 To 7
        W.Select
        W.Range("F" & A).Select
        Selection.Copy
        WB.Select
        WB.Range("I" & B).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        B = B + 1
    Next L
    
    A = A + 1
    C = C + 7
    
Loop

'Preenche a coluna N_ITEM
WB.Range("L2").Select

Set UltCel = WB.Range("K1048576").End(xlUp)

A = 2

Do While A <= UltCel.Row
    
    If WB.Range("J" & A).Value = "Standard" Then
    
        WB.Range("L" & A).Value = 1
    
    ElseIf WB.Range("J" & A).Value = "Nominal" Or WB.Range("J" & A).Value = "Umidade" Or WB.Range("J" & A).Value = "Grau_Bebida" Or _
        WB.Range("J" & A).Value = "Medicinal" Then
    
        WB.Range("L" & A).Value = 2
    
    ElseIf WB.Range("J" & A).Value = "Primeira_Entrega" Then
    
    
        WB.Range("L" & A).Value = 4
    
    ElseIf WB.Range("J" & A).Value = "Restr_Horario" Then
    
        WB.Range("L" & A).Value = 5
    
    End If


    A = A + 1
    

Loop



Application.ScreenUpdating = False

MsgBox "Pronto", vbOKOnly, "Status"

End Sub
```

Se você tiver algum problema, me chame aqui.

Espero que ajude.